# How to print the last value of every list in a list, python

Tags: python, list, loops

lets say this is my list

```
ticket=[['vvip',2,400],['vip',1,150],['side',2,200]]
```

I want to print the last item of every list in ticket

I know i can just print it like this

```
print(ticket[0][2],ticket[1][2],ticket[2][2])
```

but I want it to be in a loop, because the ticket list can have infinite list in the list

Comment: So… have you tried writing a loop?

Answer (score 2):

Use a list comprehension:

```
print([item[-1] for item in ticket])
```